# Issues with creating a column that performs a Cumulative Sum base on another columnin R Studio

Tags: r

I have this data frame. I am trying to do a cumulative value using meduan.op.only,  but it has to be grouped by part number.  This code is not working out for me since it is not doing the grouping part and it keeps the cumulative sum for all part numbers. PLease, Advice

```
structure(list(Part_No = c("2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", 
"2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", 
"2352841G1", "2352841G1"), Op = c(50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 
500, 550, 600, 700), `Op Description` = c("Kit Material", "PP&C Kit  Release", 
"WI 0150     Assemble  Housing", "WI 0200     Laser Weld Feedthus", 
"WI 0300     Helium Leak Test", "WI 0400    Temperature Shock", 
"WI 0500     Helium Leak Test", "WI 0550     Quality Inspection", 
"WI 0600     Install Connectors", "WI 0700   Install RF Absorber and Getter"
), median_Cum_Total.Op.Plus.Queue = c(0.000225347222553359, 0.00301243055473875, 
36.854632771992, 42.0687503819444, 42.1210555208336, 42.1233045138888, 
42.2217789699068, 46.613732002314, 51.1846026620365, 52.9701582002309
), median.op.only = c(0.000225347222553359, 0.000618483793956262, 
0.0190597048608793, 1.10557615740708, 0.0115505439815698, 0.0185535069444665, 
0.0088567129632941, 0.0205043344903323, 0.0253326793980819, 0.0180307060190373
), `"Part_No"` = c("Part_No", "Part_No", "Part_No", "Part_No", 
"Part_No", "Part_No", "Part_No", "Part_No", "Part_No", "Part_No"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(`"Part_No"` = "Part_No", 
    .rows = structure(list(1:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Adding Cum Median of Operation Only Again in Ascending Order
Exciter_Results <- Exciter_Results%>% 
  group_by("Part_No") %>% 
  mutate(Cum_Operation.Only_Span.in.CDays = cumsum(as.numeric(median.op.only)))
```

Comment: Try witih `dplyr::mutate` instead of `mutate`

Comment: At least for the example data you have provided there are no groups in `Part_No` (don't use the " btw).

Comment: it looks like this is giving me issues .  library(plyr)

Comment: It's usually a mistake to try to load both `dplyr` and `plyr`. Do you really need both?

Comment: from library(plyr)
all i need is 
rbind.fill(), do you know the equivalent that I can use with dplyr

Comment: You could just call it with `plyr::rbind.fill()`. But usually `dplyr::bind_rows()` will work.